# Retain ownership by uid0 and setuid bit setting while transferring binary

Tags: linux, permissions

Is there any way that if I have a binary owned by uid0 (root) and having the setuid bit set (like sudo itself) on my system, to send it to another machine with a different user while retaining these permissions? If yes, then is it possible that a binary that mocks the sudo functionality and does some additional stuff be sent to another user and running it regularly (without sudo) on his machine would grant this program escalated (root) privileges?

I am sorry if my whole understanding of this is wrong, but I read some other answers on similar questions which has really confused me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No – if you perform the transfer with your own user account on the destination system, then the new copy will always be owned by you as well.

Files aren't simply "sent", the transfer tool (on the receiving side) always has to create a *new* file and then manually set all parameters (permissions, ownership, etc.) to match what it knows about the original. So obviously the transfer tool needs to have privileges for all of this – and if it isn't running as root, it *cannot* change the new file's owner to anyone else except yourself.

---

There are possible exceptions to that. For example, you can transfer a filesystem image (e.g. an Ext4 image disguised as .iso) and have the recipient mount it. This will exactly preserve ownership and file permissions.

However, mounting a filesystem image requires root, so it still won't help you get root access on the destination system if you don't *already* have it. (In GNOME, double-clicking a disk image will mount it without requiring privileges, but will *also* set the options to ignore setuid mode – i.e. the filesystem is mounted with `nosuid` to prevent exactly this kind of trickery.)